# Tutte's 1947 proof and paper on a family of cubical graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

It is known that if a graph is connected, cubic, simple and $t$-transitive, then $t \le 5$. A proof is given in [Biggs, Algebraic Graph Theory, Chapter 18], and this result is due to [Tutte, ``A family of cubical graphs,'' Proc. Cambridge Philosophical Society, 45, 459-474].

My question is: Is the proof given in Biggs' text the same as the one in Tutte's paper?  I was unable to obtain Tutte's paper.  I would appreciate if someone could electronically post or mail to me his paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is essentially the same. Richard Weiss produced shorter proofs later - there was a lot of work on $s$-arc regular and $s$-arc transitive graphs - but even these used the same basic strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the information.